# Workaround for non-zero, non-infinite limits

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

I'm studying limits for the first time.

If we graph

$$y = \frac{x^2-1}{x-1},$$

we get a divide by zero 'hole' at $x = 1$ and $y = 2$ in an otherwise straight line. But the above can be factored to

$$y = x + 1$$

which obviates the problem.  On the other hand

$$y = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

gives us a hyperbola with the limits at infinity which doesn't seem as stupid as the 'hole' above, and this equation can't be simplified.

My question is: is it always possible to 'repair' my first equation above such that bogus 'limits' can be worked around? I"d like to hope so, since the one 'limit' number of $2$ in the otherwise unbroken line seems very weird. On the other hand, limits at zero and infinity seem quite natural.

Comment: Your first function has what is called a removable discontinuity at $x=1$. And yes, it is always possible to remove removable discontinuities.

Comment: I am hesitant to mention this since it seems you are early in your study of mathematics, but what you are asking is well discussed in the theory of [Complex Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_analysis).  The topic of [Poles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_%28complex_analysis%29), [Zeros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_%28complex_analysis%29), and [Removable Singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity) should answer this in great detail.

Comment: @Rayandrews. Once you get into the concept of a derivative, you will see that this "bogus" limit actually becomes very important, if not a crucial component of where the derivative comes from...Give it some time

Comment: Thanks all.  At my level, Zubin's answer is the most 'comfortable' since the 'x = 1, y = 2' situation is indeed what one might well call a discontinuity.  If one can always remove these things from otherwise simple line graphs then I'm content.  Derivatives ... later.  BTW I'm guessing that what you find at a discontinuity is a singularity, no?